# Wordpress: Inserting Category headers into Page TITLE

Tags: php, wordpress

To provide better information to potential visitors to my site, I'd like to have the Categories listed in the page TITLE.

For example:
Dead bankers list 2015 
would appear as
Dead bankers list 2015 | conspiracy, current affairs, higher form of life, insane, new world order, us bailout

Currently I'm able to use just one category header, but I'm aware people may be searching under any number of these to turn up my resource as a valid response.

Comment: This question is [too broad](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define new title as per your requirement in template ***single.php***

or you can add a filter as below

```html
add_filter('the_title','some_callback');
function some_callback($data){
    global $post;
    // where $data would be string(#) "current title"
    // Example:
    // (you would want to change $post->ID to however you are getting the book order #,
    // but you can see how it works this way with global $post;)
    return 'Book Order # | ' . implode(',' , get_the_category( $post_id ));
}
```

Comment: @ Webdev Workspace - This looks more like something I can use. I want it to iterate all CATEGORIES applicable to the post and put them in the <TITLE>.

Comment: The only problem being it runs this
<?php get_header(); ?>

Comment: <?php get_header(); ?> calls header.php file. You can find it in your theme's root directory.